# Scoring players over a set of games given # of games, distance traveled, and avg damage taken.

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I have a game I am working on and would like to rank players in a leaderboard.

How the game essentially works, a player has to make it between "vantage points" carrying some currency ("gold" in my case) and avoid taking damage from enemies. The player loses gold as they go on. The distance between vantage points is different for each round the player plays.

I score each player's round based off of how much gold they lose going from start to finish. So if they start the round with 10 gold and make it to the finish point with 2 gold taken they will be given a score of 8 for that match.

The thing is, is on the leaderboard I would like to rank the players based off of the # of games they've played, the avg # of points they get for all rounds, and how far they actually travel per each round. I take into account the distance of the round because 1 player who travels 10 KM and finishes with a score of 8 should be ranked higher than a player who travels 5 KM and finishes with a score of 9 (since the first player had more opportunities to have gold stolen).

A super simple solution I can think is just to sum the (distance * score) for each round and sum them together for each player and rank on whoever has the highest number. Anything wrong that could go with this?

I have read of using a Bayesian estimator from what I've read online but having a bit of difficulty incorporating the distance traveled by each player.

Comment: Is the amount of gold taken proportional to distance traveled? Also, "per each" is redundant.

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback. I would say no it isn't proportional because the players lose gold based off of their skill of avoiding the enemy not how far they travel. A player may travel 10 KM and not have ANY gold taken if they are good at avoiding the enemy :) or they could be a bad player with poor coordination and have 9 gold taken out of 10 in a 2 KM length round. Does this make sense?

Comment: I mean, given a particular level of skill, is it proportional to distance traveled?

Comment: No skill is not proportional to distance traveled. At the start of a round, a player will be given 10 gold and asked to transport it from their location to the "bank" basically which could be however far away it may be. It is a randomly generated distance between 1-10 KM.

Comment: Why did you use the tag "Game Theory"? Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with game theory or how games are defined formally in game theory.

Comment: My apologies the tag has been removed.